# How to remove hard coded file paths from python script for creating executable installer?

Tags: python, installation, py2exe, hardcoded

So I created a fairly intricate python script with a tkinter GUI that creates many user-defined text files and uses them to create and run a batch script as a sub-process which in turn creates multiple XML files that I parse for data and write to a final, single excel file using xlsxwriter.

Bottom line is this script works flawlessly on my personal machine and has file paths hard-coded into it all centered around a root folder on my desktop. For the sake of my machine, this script is great and does what it needs to do. Now, I want to get this distributed to other computers using an installer that removes necessity to have all external dependencies. I see that py2exe is a useful tool for incorporating these modules (like xlsxwriter) but I'm not sure about how to go about creating an installer that gets rid of hard coded file paths.

Essentially, I want to create something that asks the user to select where a certain program is installed on their computer (this path is used to find the location of an exe written to my batch file. For the sake of distribution, assume every computer that is installing my application has this program installed in something like C:\Program Files\Blahblah) and then asks the user where they want to install my program. Since the script creates and destroys many files during its lifetime, I want this folder to basically act like the folder I have on my desktop right now as the "root directory" of my application. I want to know the best practice for implementing and creating an installer for these file paths into my python application to make the script easy to distribute to any computer running Windows. Thanks!

Comment: Why don't you let the user choose the root directory through the UI? Tkinter has a folder selection dialog, it doesn't need to be the same as the executable's location.

Comment: I like this simplicity, so I am going to ensure the user specifies a root directory and the executables location prior to running the script for the first time. I will write these to a text file in the root directory. Upon startup, the program will check if this text file exists and if so, it will load the file paths specified. If not, it will prompt the user to choose the directories. Then I can just package up this complete .py file and its dependencies as an executable using py2exe. Hope this works - thank you Jon!